# How to avoid all empty tags from Jaxb XML

Tags: xml, spring, xsd, jaxb

hi I am creating a xml from XSD using maven plug in and marshalling it using JAXB.
But the XML is coming with empty tags if the value is not there. How i can avoid it globally .Below is the sample empty tags i am getting in my XML . I dont need any of these tags if it is empty . Is there any way we can achieve it in XSD of JAXB level ?

```
<INDIVIDUAL>
    <NAME>
        <FirstName></FirstName>
        <LastName></LastName>
    </NAME>
</INDIVIDUAL>
```

Marshaling it as

```
StringResult result = new StringResult();
JAXBContext jaxbContext     = JAXBContext.newInstance( MESSAGE.class );
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller   = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(messageObj,result);
```

Comment: Are `FirstName` and `LastName` null or empty Strings?

Comment: i am setting it as null if values are not there

Comment: Which JAXB implementation are you using?

Comment: Updated the question with marshalling

Comment: Still, my question remains. Which is the implementation of JAXB you are using?

Comment: i see it as  org.glassfish.jaxb

Answer (score 0):

Given that you seem to be using the reference implementation for JAXB (JSR-222) it does not marshal a property annotated with `@XmlAttribute` that contains a null value. Having said that, try annotating `FirstName` and `LastName` attributes in your model class with `@XmlAttribute`.